# How add unique text and textfield to the div I just created?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Javascript Create Div Element Dynamically</title>

    <style type="text/css">
.ex
{
width:200px;
position: relative;
background-color :#CCC;
height:150px;
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
left-margin:0px;
float :left;
}
#newdiv
{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
 border:1px solid #000;     
}
.border
{
 border:1px solid #000; 
}

    </style>
<script>

image.cc=1;
function changeimage(image)
{
if (image.cc==0) 
  {
  image.cc=1;
  $(image).attr('src', 'images/white_contact.png');
  }
else if (image.cc==1)
  {
  image.cc=2;
  $(image).attr('src', 'images/yellow_contact.png');
  }
  else if (image.cc==2)
  {
  image.cc=3;
    $(image).attr('src', 'images/green_contact.png');
  }
    else
  {
  image.cc=0;
    $(image).attr('src', 'images/red_contact.png');
  }
}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var i=0;
    function createDiv()
    {


  if(i < 6) {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = "div"+i;
        divTag.setAttribute("align","left");
        divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";
        divTag.className ="ex";
       divTag.innerHTML = "<img class='myimage' onclick='changeimage(this)' border='0' src='images/white_contact.png' width='60'/>";

        document.getElementById("newdiv").appendChild(divTag)

      }

   i++;
   $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6});
 $( ".ex" ).droppable({ hoverClass:'border' });

    }





    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p align="left">
        <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically:</b>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="create div" onClick="createDiv();" />

        <div id = "newdiv">

</div>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I managed to create 6 div with different image property in each div.

I wanted to add table inside each of my divtag also to place it beside my images, but I realise I cannot just append Table beside the image. how can add table inside

I want to add text and textbox in table too.

My table is like that

```
<table border='0'><tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

- There are various ways to position objects next to each other.
  Just one example, `$(yourNewObj).find('*').css({"float":"left"});`
- To dynamically create new elements, you can do something like exampled below:

  ```
  $myTable = $("<table />").attr({"id":"foo","class":"bar"}).css({"display":"block","width":"30%","float":"left"});
  $firstTR = $myTable.append("<tr />");
  /* ... */    
  $myTable.append($firstTR);
  /* ... */
  yournewObj.append($myTable);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My advice here would be to read into some of the methods jQuery provides – it will make much of what you're doing easier. For instance, you can create your `<div/>`s with code like this:

```
$('#newdiv').append('<div id="div"'+i+'" class="ex" style="text-align: left;"><img class="myimage" onclick="changeimage(this)" border="0" src="images/white_contact.png" width="60"/></div>');`
```

After you've created it, you can append your table HTML in the same way.

```
$('#newdiv').find('#div'+i).append('<table border="0"><tr>'+
    '<td>Name:</td>'+
    '<td><input type="text"></td>'+
  '</tr><tr>'+
    '<td>Title:</td>'+
    '<td><input type="text"></td>'+
  '</tr>'+
  '<tr>'+
    '<td>Contact:</td>'+
    '<td><input type="text"></td>'+
  '</tr>'+
'</table>');
```

If this is for a project, and not just trying to learn how to dynamically generate things with JS, it's preferable to not generate quite so much of your view with JavaScript. It's better to specify styling in separate CSS stylesheets and, if possible, to write your HTML using templates ([examples](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/best-practices-when-working-with-javascript-templates/)) and/or to generate it back-end.

Instead of `divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";` you can simply do `$('#div1').css('margin', '0px auto');`. This is true for any CSS you might need to set with jQuery, but try to do it in stylesheets when you can.

You'll need to use CSS to make the table appear beside the image instead of just below it. The CSS float:left property applied to both (the image and the table) would probably do the trick.